# "java: Duplicate methods named XXX" issue when using Eclipse compiler in IDEA with JDK 8

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, intellij-idea, java-8

With the following simple class I get `java: Duplicate methods named spliterator with the parameters () and () are inherited from the types java.util.List<T> and java.lang.Iterable<T>` error if using Eclipse compiler in IDEA with JDK 8:

```
public class Java8Test {
    public static interface Traverable<T> extends Iterable<T> {}
    public static interface List<T> extends Traverable<T>, java.util.List<T> {}
}
```

If change the compiler to javac, then there is no error. The error also gone if switched to JDK 6 with eclipse compiler.

IDEA version: 12.1.5

Comment: Eclipse doesn't support Java 8 yet.

Comment: oops don't know that. I will leave this question here in case other people has the same confusion

Comment: As of 4.4 Eclipse supports Java 8.  The 4.3 release can be upgraded to Java 8 but does not support it out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when trying to compile Java 7 code with a Java 8 JDK.

The solution that worked for me was changing the JRE configured in Eclipse to a Java 7 one: `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs`. Edit the existing one and select a directory containing a Java 7 JDK.

Comment: Project-Java Build Path-Libraries-Add Library-JRE System Libray-Choose java 7 and delete java 8. This can change project specific setting if u don't want to change Eclipse settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seem that Eclipse's 4.3 JTD is not carrying on well with Java8. On the words of Stephan Herrmann (CLA):

> A Java 7 compiler should never try to compile against a JRE 8. True
>   compatibility for the scenario is not specified anywhere and may not
>   even be possible because of default methods that have been added to
>   the libraries in a way that ensures runtime compatibility of old code
>   but
>   *not* compile time compatibility with a Java 7 compiler and new libraries. Hence I'm marking this bug as invalid, it's s.t. we cannot
>   support by design.

You may read more in here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407010

and here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409473

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390889

Comment: In other words, do not use a given version of a Java compiler in a newer version of Java than the Java compiler supports.  If you want Java 8, run on Java 8.